# How do I build react and node together?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've encountered a slight problem. I know that I can build react-app using `npm run build` and it will create optimized build folder which I can load to production. But some days ago I started to use `node.js` with my `react` application. I am confused now - how should I build such an app now?

My folders structure:

```
my-app-| 
       |-client-|
       |        |-package.json // root react package file
       |
       |
       |- server.js // node.js (express) root file
       |- package.json // root node package file
```

**EDIT 1**

```
> server@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Horseman.mini\PhpstormProjects\landing
> npm run build && cd ./client && npm run build


> server@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Horseman.mini\PhpstormProjects\landing
> npm run build && cd ./client && npm run build


> server@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Horseman.mini\PhpstormProjects\landing
> npm run build && cd ./client && npm run build


> server@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Horseman.mini\PhpstormProjects\landing
> npm run build && cd ./client && npm run build

'npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 build: `npm run build && cd ./client && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Horseman.mini\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-22T14_49_23_308Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 build: `npm run build && cd ./client && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Horseman.mini\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-22T14_49_23_345Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 build: `npm run build && cd ./client && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

PS `npm --version` returns `6.14.10`

If I go to client folder and build it will build, but without server side

Answer (score 0):

You can now delegate the responsibility of serving your frontend build folder to the `server.js` i.e the server only. The simplest thing could be using `express.static` to serve the frontend like so :-

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./dist")));` where `app` is the instance of your `express` server.

where `./dist` is the relative path to your root folder so something like `my-app/dist` where you place your build files. Again it's totally upto you what name you want to use. Essentially all the static files i.e **js,css and html** will be part of this `dist` folder and will be served to the user when he/she hits the base path. Since both frontend and backend would be available from the same server, there would not be any need to handle **CORS** scenarios as well unless well it's absolutely required by your implementation.

Comment: After adding `app.use ...` to my `server.js` file - should I build my project  like that? - Enter in the root of my-app `npm run build`, or not?

Comment: @WhoAmI You can build the files using the existing command and maybe copy them to a separate folder like `dist` outside your client app ? You can also try giving the path to your build folder directly in `app.use` first to check whether the content is being served right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using parent folder with `package.json` and put your respective build commands in that.

```
my-app-| 
       |-client-|
       |        |-package.json // root react package file
       |
       |
       |- server.js // node.js (express) root file
       |- package.json // root node package file ---> add build command for front and back here.
```

Your root `package.json` can have following command.

```
{
   "build": "npm run build && cd ./client && npm run build"
}
```

This will build your backend first and then frontend, if you want both command to run simultaneously then you can use package like [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

Comment: I added command, entered in terminal `npm run build` and it launched several times and crashed, please see edit in my question

Comment: check your setup and installation again.